# about convergence of $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty \:}\left(-1\right)^{n+1}\ln \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I sorry maybe this is so easy for you, I need to know if the serie:

$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty \:}\left(-1\right)^{n+1}\ln \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$

converge or not converge?

Comment: Never too easy.

Comment: Have you tried the alternating series test?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Leibniz test for alternating series.

Comment: Is it sufficient with Leibniz criterion?...

Comment: What is the Leibniz criterion and does your series satisfy it?

Comment: I know what is Leibniz criterion and the series satisfy that, my question is, is it sufficient with that?...

Comment: If you prove that the series is alternating and that the absolute values of it elements are monotonically decreasing, then, by Leibniz's argument, the series converges.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution:

If $a_n \to 0$ note that $$\sum_{n=1}^{2k} a_n$$ $$\sum_{n=1}^{2k+1} a_n$$ $$\sum_{n=1}^{k} a_n$$ either all converge (and to the same sum) or all diverge when $k \to \infty$. Now let us take a look at the first sum. $$\sum_{n=1}^{2k} a_n=\sum_{n=0}^{k} (a_{2n+1}+a_{2n+2})=\sum_{n=0}^{k-1} \left( \ln \left( 1+\frac{1}{2n+1}  \right)-\ln \left( 1+\frac{1}{2n+2} \right) \right)=\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}\ln \left( 1+\frac{1}{3+8 n+4 n^2} \right) $$

I hope you can carry on from here, if you need more help, let me know.